# disable css scroll smooth on scrollTo

Tags: javascript, css

My element has css `scroll-behavior:smooth`, which I'm using in order to smooth the hash "a href" links.

I want the page to first load on a fixed position on the page, which means it won't "smooth" the scroll on the first load to that position and only use it after.

I don't want to use any setTimeOut hack, I know that scrollTo has "options" that are widely supported, but I can't find any type of "behavior" that will override the css smoothness.

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question right - Without any setTimeout - the first thing that pops my mind is to simply add using JS a class (like i.e: `smoothScroll-init`) to all the `class="smoothScroll"` elements:

HTML:

```html
<div class="smoothScroll">Still not smooth...</div>
```

CSS:

```css
/* Will be added by JS on DOM ready */
.smoothScroll-init {           
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

JS:

```
// DOM is ready
// Add class "smoothScroll-init" to all class "smoothScroll" elements:
document.querySelectorAll(".smoothScroll").forEach(EL => EL.classList.add("smoothScroll-init"));
```

If you're targeting a specific Element that you want to target and snap-scroll into view use: [Element/scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#parameters) using the `{behavior: "auto"}` option.